# Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: php, laravel

```
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('title');
                $table->text('body');
                $table->string('image')->nullable();
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->integer('category_id');
                $table->timestamps();

                $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            });

Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();    
        });
```

---->
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete cascade)

Comment: they are created sequentially, so is first created posts and then categories, the order should be switched, or the constrain added in a migration at the bottom

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you still have problems with the question?

Answer (score 1):

Categories needs to exist before the foreign key is created, as you can not foreign key to a table that does not exists yet.

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
});

Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ...
});
```

Secondly when you do a foreign key, you will have to have the `id` as the same type as the tables foreign key. When you do `increments('id')` it will actually create an unsigned integer, therefor your `category_id` in posts should be an unsigned integer.

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('category_id');

    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```